# Seed fair amounts of, and structured, data in Phoenix

Tags: mysql, phoenix-framework, seed

I'm trying to figure out a way to seed two tables from an old project into a new phoenix project. One table has city names with an id. Another table has addresses that are connected to those cities, by their id. If I just seed a list of cities by name, ids will be messed up. o_0

I'm thinking perhaps I could create a folder "seed-data" next to 
priv/repo/seeds.exs
and somehow include it. Still learning and haven't used the File before.
Or perhaps include a raw sql export from old project, and then import it ?! :D

"seed data phoenix" gave me three results(SO), and slack group suggested I go SO, so here I am! :D